# \lhead already defined error

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, thesis

I am writing my thesis by using `isuthesis` package.
I want page numbers  to come at the middle of bottom of the page. For that I thought of using `fancyhdr` package.

```
\documentclass[answers,a4paper]{isuthesis}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

I get the build error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \lhead already defined.
>              Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Please help in solving this error.

Comment: presumably the thesis package you are using already has an lhead command for setting the heading, so you should use that. you'll need to look to its documentation

Comment: The `isuthesis.cls` from the Iowa State University can be obtained here: [isuthesis.zip](http://www.grad-college.iastate.edu/current/thesis/Tex/isuthesiscomplete/isuthesiscomplete.zip) It does in fact define the `\lhead` etc. commands already. However, it seems in some portions to be outdated

Comment: I am not an expert in latex, so not able to understand documentation  of .cls file well. Please suggest how to get page numbers at middle of the bottom of the page?

Comment: `\cfoot{\thepage}` without `hancyhdr`?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the class already defines commands like `\lhead` or `cfoot`, you can just use them.

By default, the pagenumber is set in the center of the head, you first need to clear this field or the page number will appear two times on the page.

```
\documentclass{isuthesis}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\chead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```